# What are some reliable ways to buy bitcoin with paypal or credit card

Tags: buy-bitcoins, paypal

I'm looking to buy bitcoins all i could find are some old ways on google and questions in this site, but couldn't know which one is the best, how do you guys buy bitcoins?